# Транзакции MySQL или как застолбить будущее

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

Допустим, имеем следующие записи:

*voyages*

+------+------------+-------------------+

|   id   | direction | shipment_at   |

+------+------------+-------------------+

|   1    |     456    |   2020-02-10   |

+------+------------+-------------------+

|   2    |     201    |   2020-02-15   |

+------+------------+-------------------+

|   3    |     382    |   2020-02-15   |

+------+------------+-------------------+

Теперь мне нужно внести новые записи с помощью выгрузки, на пример 3 штуки, но при этом, внести их таким образом, чтоб следующие `id` были ими заняты, теперь индексы `4, 5, 6` заняты до момента пока полностью не закончится выгрузка.

Что я имею ввиду, если человек во время импорта решит внести новый рейс ручками, то чтоб новый рейс уже занял `7` индекс.

Зачем так надо долго объяснять, но вот такая штука

Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> create table test (id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
>                    val int) engine=InnoDB auto_increment=1;
> ```

> ```
> insert into test (val) values (11),(22),(33);
> ```

Резервируем три записи, id=4..6.

> ```
> ALTER TABLE test AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
> ```

> ```
> insert into test (val) values (44),(55),(66);
> ```

Вставляем записи на зарезервированные места

> ```
> insert into test (id, val) values (4,444),(5,555),(6,666);
> ```

> ```
> insert into test (val) values (77),(88),(99);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 |  11
>  2 |  22
>  3 |  33
>  4 | 444
>  5 | 555
>  6 | 666
>  7 |  44
>  8 |  55
>  9 |  66
> 10 |  77
> 11 |  88
> 12 |  99
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=15762c614a49feb52f87e237f7e16d29)*

Comment: Ой какая красота, спасибо :)